# Email not send in function codeigniter php mailer

Tags: phpmailer, codeigniter-3

this controller code. 
i found problem that "Failed to send password, please try again!" . 
What should I do?

```
    $mail_message='Dear '.$row[0]['name'].','. "\r\n";
    $mail_message.='Your <b>Password</b> is <b>'.$passwordplain.'</b>'."\r\n";
    $mail_message.='<br>Please Update your password.';
    $mail_message.='<br>Thanks & Regards';
    $mail_message.='<br>IT Ardiles';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSendmail();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = '';                           
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Host = "mail.xxxxx.co.id";
    $subject = 'Forgot Password';
    $mail->AddAddress(xxx@xxxxx.co.id);
    $mail->IsMail();
    $mail->From = 'it@xxxxx.co.id';
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxx';
    $mail->FromName = 'IT';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $mail_message;
    $mail->Send();
```

Comment: Why are you calling `isSendmail()`? It’s extremely unlikely that’s what you need, especially given that you have provided SMTP connection details. Call `isSMTP()` instead.

Comment: Incidentally, if you have a user’s password in plain text, you are doing something very wrong with your authentication.

Comment: I just need to solve the problem. why can not send email? even though isSendmail() I've deleted but still can not send email

Comment: So solve the problem, don’t just complain about it. Deleting `isSendmail` is not enough; do what I said. Set `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what’s going on in SMTP.

Comment: found the error 2018-06-28 20:33:55 Could not instantiate mail function. 2018-06-28 20:33:56 Could not instantiate mail function.

Comment: That tells me you *didn't* do what I said. You've fallen back to using `mail()`, and you don't have a local mail server configured (which would also explain why sendmail didn't work either). Call `isSMTP()` and you might actually get somewhere.